# Printing the multidimensional array with column as the outer loop

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

If you are trying to display your two dimensional array going down the column and you are getting an out of bound exception, what is the best way to resolve the issue? Would you throw the exception? Thank you in advance!

```
/*print out the array contents going down the columns from the first column to the last*/ 
for (int col=0;col<stuff.length; col++) { 
    for (int row=0;row<stuff[col].length;row++) { 
        System.out.print(stuff[row][col]); System.out.print(" "); 
    } 
    System.out.println(); 
}
```

Comment: "I tried to post my code as an image" why would you want to do that? Why not just post it as text?

Answer (score 1):

Change row and col in your array:

```
for (int row=0;col<stuff.length; row++) { 
    for (int col=0;row<stuff[row].length;col++) { 
        System.out.print(stuff[row][col]); System.out.print(" "); 
    } 
    System.out.println(); 

}
```